# Java Eclipse - Game: How to make the user's answer change the next statement asked

Tags: java

Right now I am working on a programming project in school, I am using Java Eclipse. I am still learning the basics, as I am a Sophomore in high school.

My project relates to the old game called "20 Questions".

My main trouble right now is making the user's answer result with a different question. I have tried and "if else" statement, which took me far, but not far enough. Example:

```
print ("Is your animal furry?");

if (answer is "True") print("Does this animal wag its tail when excited?") 
//This can only be a dog

else print("Is it known to lick itself clean?")
//Else meaning if it doesn't wag its tail, go to cat questions
//only cat in this program
```

So my predicament is getting the user's answer to change the programs next answer.
Then if the answer they give to the furry animal is false, how do I make it go to the non hairy animal questions?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Java game, or any Java application with a GUI, using the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) helps separate your concerns and makes it a lot easier to code.

What you're missing is a model.  Here's one way you could model the 20 questions game.

**Question.java**

Here's a class that holds the question string and two pointers.  One pointer for the true answer, and one pointer for the false answer.

```
package com.ggl.twenty.questions;

public class Question {

    private int falseQuestion;
    private int trueQuestion;

    private String question;

    public Question(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public int getFalseQuestion() {
        return falseQuestion;
    }

    public void setFalseQuestion(int falseQuestion) {
        this.falseQuestion = falseQuestion;
    }

    public int getTrueQuestion() {
        return trueQuestion;
    }

    public void setTrueQuestion(int trueQuestion) {
        this.trueQuestion = trueQuestion;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

}
```

**TwentyQuestionsModel.java**

Next, we create a model class for the game.  This class creates and uses a List of questions.  From any question, you can get the next question by performing the getTrueQuestion or getFalseQuestion method.

```
package com.ggl.twenty.questions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TwentyQuestionsModel {

    private int questionIndex;

    private List<Question> questions;

    public TwentyQuestionsModel() {
        this.questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        this.questionIndex = 0;
        loadQuestions();
    }

    private void loadQuestions() {
        Question q0 = new Question("Is it a vegetable?");
        this.questions.add(q0);
        Question q1 = new Question("Is it a mineral?");
        this.questions.add(q1);
        Question q2 = new Question("Is it a mammal?");
        this.questions.add(q2);
        // ...
        q0.setFalseQuestion(1);
        q0.setTrueQuestion(3);
        // ...
    }

    public String getTrueQuestion() {
        Question q = questions.get(questionIndex);
        this.questionIndex = q.getTrueQuestion();
        return questions.get(questionIndex).getQuestion();
    }

    public String getFalseQuestion() {
        Question q = questions.get(questionIndex);
        this.questionIndex = q.getFalseQuestion();
        return questions.get(questionIndex).getQuestion();
    }

    public String getFirstQuestion() {
        return questions.get(questionIndex).getQuestion();
    }
}
```

You still have to code a view and a controller.  The right model makes it much easier, as you can separate your concerns.

Comment: Although the use of `int` allows for easy mapping, I would personally have `Question` contain two other questions: One for "yes" and one for "no". Then, depending on the answer, the current question is set to one of the encapsulated questions. That way, not only is it less cryptic, but you can prevent mis-use

Comment: @Vince Emigh: I understand your point, but with your schema, how do you get to the third question?  I basically mapped a tree structure to a List.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution just with a question class:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question {

```
private String message = null;
private boolean answered = false;
private Question yes = null;
private Question no = null;

public Question(String message)
{
    this.message = message;
}

public void setAnswered(boolean answered)
{
    this.answered = answered;
}
public boolean getAnswered()
{
    return this.answered;
}
public void setYes(Question yes)
{
    this.yes = yes;
}
public void setNo(Question no)
{
    this.no = no;
}
public Question getYes()
{
    return this.yes;
}
public Question getNo()
{
    return this.no;
}
public String getMessage()
{
    return this.message;
}

public static void runQuestionnaire(Question startQuestion)
{
    String yes = "y";
    System.out.println("Some questions. Type 'y' for yes and 'n' for no\nand press enter.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = null;

    Question current = startQuestion;
    boolean answered = false;
    do
    {
        System.out.println(current.getMessage());
        answer = sc.next();
        if(answer.equals(yes))
        {
            current = current.getYes();
        }
        else
        {
            current = current.getNo();
        }
        answered = current.getAnswered();
    }
    while(!answered);
    System.out.println(current.getMessage());
    sc.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // creating the question tree
    Question startQuestion = new Question("Is it fury?");
    Question yes1 = new Question("Has it 4 legs?");
    Question no1 = new Question("It is a human beeing.");
    no1.setAnswered(true);
    startQuestion.setYes(yes1);
    startQuestion.setNo(no1);
    Question yes11 = new Question("Is it blue?");
    Question yes111 = new Question("It is a whale.");
    yes111.setAnswered(true);
    Question no111 = new Question("It is a bear.");
    no111.setAnswered(true);
    yes1.setYes(yes11);
    Question no11 = new Question("It is a bird.");
    no11.setAnswered(true);
    yes1.setNo(no11);
    yes11.setYes(yes111);
    yes11.setNo(no111);

    Question.runQuestionnaire(startQuestion);
}
```